# How to find list is NOT empty in Mustache

Tags: mustache

We have a requirement to display some message if the documents list in the below data structure is NOT empty.

```
    {
      "id:" 1,
      "documents": [
          {
             "name": "2353626.jpg",
             "type": "image"
          }
      ]
    }
```

Initially we thought of adding a flag in the JSON and tried to render the mustache template. But we would like to avoid this as we feel that we are polluting our API response for the UI.

```
    "hasDocuments": true
```

**Approach 1:**

We were trying to display a message based on the 0th element

```
    {{#documents.0}}
       Documents available
    {{/documents.0}}
    {{^documents}}
       Documents missing
    {{/documents}}
```

This works well in **mustache.js** but we need to use an extension for **mustache.java** to make it work @ https://gist.github.com/spullara/5331831

**Approach 2:**

We were trying to access empty method

```
    {{^documents.empty}}
       Documents available
    {{/documents.empty}}
```

Unfortunately this is NOT supported in **mustache.js** but works well in **mustache.java**

We are planning to go with 0th element approach. Is there a better way to identify whether a list is NOT empty?

Comment: did you try with `{{#documents.length}}`?

Comment: Thanks for the hint about using `.empty`, that helped my use case.

Comment: Helped me too. context: Openapi spec gen for oneOf  go-server autogen: openapi-generator-cli mustache lib does not handle the `.0` and `.length` cases, but do work with `^*.empty`